# Several conditions filter on javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck with this problem. There is a simple filter and it works not exactly the way I need it: http://jsfiddle.net/qyy810xx/
CSS here:

```
.categorya, .categoryb, .categoryrko {

    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size:11px;
    color:white;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
.categoryb {
    background: blue;
}

.categorya.categoryb{
    background:purple;
}
p.info{
    padding:30px 20px 0 20px;
    color:#666;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="categorya" id="filter-categorya" />
        <label for="filter-categorya">Category A</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="categoryb" id="filter-categoryb" />
        <label for="filter-categoryb">Category B</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="categoryrko" id="filter-categoryrko" />
        <label for="filter-categoryrko">RKO</label>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="categorya categoryb">A, B</div>
<div class="categorya">A</div>
<div class="categorya">A</div>
<div class="categorya">A</div>
<div class="categoryrko">RKO</div>
<div class="categoryb categoryrko">BRko</div>
<div class="categoryb">B</div>
<div class="categoryb">B</div>
```

And script:

```
 $("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {

   var re = new RegExp($("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
                          return this.value;
                       }).get().join("|") );
   $("div").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this[re.source!="" && re.test($this.attr("class")) ? "show" : "hide"]();
   });
});
```

If select `categoryB` we can see ONLY  divs with `categoryB` class, but i need to see all divs, including `categoryB` class.
e.g. if you select `categoryA` it must display [A,B] block, all [A] blocks and [RKOa] block, but if you select `categoryA` AND `categoryRKO` it must show ONLY [RKOa] block. i.e. only a block that satisfies all parameters.

I will be glad to any help

Answer (score 1):

You need not make a regular expression, **just formulate a selector** using the same logic

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {

   var selector = $("#filters :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
                          return "." + this.value;
                  }).get().join(",");
   $("div").hide().filter(selector).show(); //now show only those which are matching the selector chosen above
});
```

Comment: ty for feedback, but unfortunately i have no idea what to do with your advice

Comment: @PetrVoloshin Here is the updated fiddle with my changes http://jsfiddle.net/qyy810xx/1/

Comment: ty but it doesn't react if i choose only one checkbox and if i choose `categoryA` + `categoryB` it shows all divs, that have and `categoryA` or `categoryB`. Not only divs, that have both :c

Comment: @PetrVoloshin Check now http://jsfiddle.net/qyy810xx/2/ You were binding a click inside the click event.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you're trying to do. But be honest your code was really hard for other to read. So I decided to come up with a better solution and easy for everyone to know what I'm trying to do when they're reading code.

The idea is: Every times you check a checkbox.

1. You map through all checkboxes and push the value of checked checkbox into an `array`.
2. Then hide all div
3. And finally loop through an `array` and show the checked one.

Here is modified code of your's. :) Hope it can give you a idea.

```js
    $(".filter-checkbox").click(function() {
   var checkboxes = $('.filter-checkbox');
      var checkedClasses = [];
      //Map and get all checked category
      var activeCheckboxes = checkboxes.each(function(index,checkbox){
       if(checkbox.checked)
         checkedClasses.push(checkbox.value);
      });
      //Hide all category
      $('.category').hide();
      //Show only checked
      $.each(checkedClasses,function(index,className){
       $('.' + className).show();
      })
    });
```

```css
.categorya, .categoryb, .categoryrko {
    
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size:11px;
    color:white;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.categoryb {
    background: blue;
}

.categorya.categoryb{
    background:purple;
}
p.info{
    padding:30px 20px 0 20px;
    color:#666;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters">
    <li>
        <input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="categorya" id="filter-categorya" />
        <label for="filter-categorya">Category A</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="categoryb" id="filter-categoryb" />
        <label for="filter-categoryb">Category B</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="categoryrko" id="filter-categoryrko" />
        <label for="filter-categoryrko">RKO</label>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="category categorya categoryb">A, B</div>
<div class="category categorya">A</div>
<div class="category categorya">A</div>
<div class="category categorya">A</div>
<div class="category categoryrko">RKO</div>
<div class="category categoryb">B</div>
<div class="category categoryb">B</div>
<div class="category categoryb">B</div>

<br />
<p class="info">
    - If you select Category A: four boxes will apear [A,B] [A] [A] [A]
    <br/><br/>
    - Then if you select Category B and deselect it again: the purple box [A,B] will disapear because the script commands to hide 'B'.
    <br/><br/>
    - But I don't want the script to hide box 'B' when it also contains 'A'..
</p>
```

Comment: ty for edits! Seems like i got what you mean, but unfortunately can't make it working :)

Comment: I make it working on codepen. You can check it out: https://codepen.io/cqpro/pen/JOmxma

Comment: yeah, now i can see it working, ty! but there is one problem - when i choose 2 checkboxes, filter showing me blocks, that have one of choosec classes, but i need to see only one block, witch contains both classes :(

Comment: Ohhh. I got what you mean. When you select A and B. The result will be block A,B show. 
I was edit my codepen as your requirement. Could you pls check it. If it's ok. I will edit my answer as well. :D